# Unable to create a trace file in Android 2.3 using Debug.startMethodTracing

Tags: android, performance-testing

```
     Debug.startMethodTracing("tracefile");
```

Getting exception while executing above line of code in Android 2.3

```
     java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to open trace file '/sdcard/copy.trace': Permission denied
```

I have added required permission in AndroidManifest file:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

My device is from a view server.
Anybody could suggest me any suitable solution for this.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Does your device have actual external storage? For example, if you are doing this on an emulator, did you give your emulator image a virtual SD card?

Answer (score 0):

If this is an emulator, edit the device in AVD and verify that the SD Card: has memory allocated.